# how to add/insert conditional node into XML using linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I generated an xml file like this:

```
 XElement employees =
        new XElement("Work",
           new XElement("record",
              new XElement("Name", textBox1.Text),
              new XElement("Phone", "206-555-0144"),
              new XElement("Address",
                    new XElement("Street1", "123 Main St"),
                    new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
                    new XElement("State", "WA"),
                    new XElement("Postal", "68042")
             )),
             new XElement("record",
              new XElement("Name", "22222"),
              new XElement("Phone", "353245345"),
              new XElement("Address",
                    new XElement("Street1", "sdfain St"),
                    new XElement("City", "asdf Island"),
                    new XElement("State", "QLD"),
                    new XElement("Postal", "54322")
              )),
              new XElement("record",
              new XElement("Name", "Peter"),
              new XElement("Phone", "1234"),
              new XElement("Address",
                    new XElement("Street1", "sd St"),
                    new XElement("City", "cbr"),
                    new XElement("State", "act"),
                    new XElement("Postal", "2600")
              )
          )
      );
```

Later I wish to add new child node under parent node "record" based on a condition (where name="peter"), something like this:

```
empFile.Elements().Where(r => (string)r.Element("Name") == "Peter")
                  .Add(new XElement("record",
                           new XElement("Mobile", "3253425"),
                           new XElement("Work", 999999)
                       ));
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Nitpick: Instead of `(string)r.Element("Name")`, I would suggest that using `r.Element("Name").Value` may be better form.

Comment: @Timwi: I wouldn't. The advantage of the cast to string is that it returns null instead of blowing up when cast from null. So any element without a subelement called Name is just ignored, instead of causing the program to fail. I almost always prefer to use the explicit conversions in LINQ to XML, unless failure to find an element/attribute should be considered bad enough to warrant an exception.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Fair point. I admit I didn’t think of null, but even if I did, it isn’t obvious that `op_Explicit` accepts it and doesn’t throw. It is also not obvious what `op_Explicit` does if, for example, the element has subelements, whereas the documentation for the `Value` property is more explicit (haha, the irony) about it.

Comment: @Timwi: The documentation for the explicit conversion looks pretty clear to me: "If the XElement has children, the concatenated string value of all of the element's text and descendant's text is returned."

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That does look pretty clear, but I have no idea where you got it from. For me it says: “Summary: Cast the value of this XElement to a string. Parameters: element: The XElement to cast to string. Returns: A string that contains the content of this XElement.” Not clear at all.

Comment: @Timwi: Online MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Has it occurred to anyone at Microsoft to update the documentation shipped with the framework so that it is at least as useful as the one on MSDN? I am surprised that they are not in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, your Where clause returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` not a single XElement, so you just need to fix that, i.e. call .Single() or .First() etc

eg:

```
XElement xe = empFile.Elements().Where(r => (string)r.Element("Name") == "Peter").Single();

xe.Add(new XElement("record", new XElement("Mobile", "3253425"), new XElement("Work", 999999));
```

Comment: u have assigned Empfile. elements(). blahblah to xe
and xe.add new elements, but i found the empFile has been updated as well, how come?

Answer (score 4):

As well as Tim's suggestion of using `Where` followed by `Single` or `First`, it's worth knowing that there are overloads of those methods which already take predicates. For example:

```
empFile.Elements()
       .Single(r => (string) r.Element("Name") == "Peter")
       .Add(...);
```